# If i pluck 2 values, how can i read them in html ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller i find a uniq notebook and user name.
but i want to be able to check in my html code that it shows only one type of user.

in controller

```
def index
  @allnotebooks = Note.uniq.pluck(:string, :notebook)
  @notes = Note.all
end
```

in my html

```
<% @allnotebooks.each do |notebook| %>
  <% if notebook.string == c_user.name %>
    <option><%= notebook %></option>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

notebook.string does not work. what am i missing

Comment: Found answer its just like calling an array in C. notebook[0]

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do in different way other than using pluck, using select you can do it
 like-

In controller code-

def index

@allnotebooks = Note.uniq.select([:string, :notebook])

@notes = Note.all

end

in your html

```
<% @allnotebooks.each do |notebook| %>

<% if notebook.string == c_user.name %>

<option><%= notebook %></option>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pluck returns an array.

Try `notebook.first` or `notebook[0]`

Docs here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Second example at the bottom applies here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a good ruby guy, You can write it like

```
<% @allnotebooks.each_with_index do |notebook, index| %>
<%= notebook[index].string %> => <%= notebook[index].notebook %>
<% end %>
```

for "a" unique notebook, you do you need to loop it?
just to say:

```
@allnotebooks.each{|notebook| <%= notebook[0] %> <%= notebook[1] %> }
```

But there can be better ways.

Answer (score 0):

In your example it should be:

```
<% @allnotebooks.each do |notebook| %>
  <% if notebook[0] == c_user.name %>
    <option><%= notebook[1] %></option>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

btw you might want to improve this by only loading notebooks where the string equals your user's name.